# Inverse of symmetric matrix with 1 on diagonal

Tags: matrices, inverse

I'm looking for ways to solve the inverse of a symmetric matrix with 1's on the diagonal and all entries $x_{ij}$ continues variables within the range $(-1,1)$. The matrix thus looks like:
 \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & x_{12} & x_{13} & \dots  & x_{1m} \\
    x_{12} & 1 & x_{23} & \dots  & x_{2m} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    x_{1m} & x_{2m} & x_{3m} & \dots  & 1
\end{bmatrix}

Is there a way to solve this matrix analytically for any $m$? How should I go about to try and solve this?

Thanks a lot for any advice on this!

Greets

Comment: I reckon there will be nothing simpler than good old $\frac{1}{\det M}(Com(M))^T$. This is too close to the general case.

Comment: Also note that $\pmatrix {1 & a \\ a & 1}$ is invertible for $|a| < 1$, but for $|a| = 1$, it's not. So some of your matrices are *very nearly* not invertible. If you're hoping to find a useful formula and use a computer to evaluate it, this non-invertibility may be revealed in floating-point sensitivity: a tiny change to one entry makes a massive change to one or more entries in the inverse. Frankly, for computations: you're probably better off using the SVD and/or pseduoinverse.

Comment: Hmm yeah I know.. I was hoping there was some rule I was missing, because it's part of a greater problem for which I would like to have a nice expression for this problem. A few months ago, I was stuck on this same issue, but with a fixed $x$ and someone found a solution to simplify it very nicely. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2544652/stuck-for-generalization-of-a-proof-on-specific-linear-system-of-equations/2545044?noredirect=1#comment5255944_2545044  I guess I was hoping on finding something similar :)

Comment: .This is a positive definite matrix. Maybe it can be helpful to you: Study Cholesky decomposition method and SVD method in matrix analysis